# Loop in BigQuery (SQL - GOOGLE CLOUD)

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

I would like to know how to perform a loop in bigquery to create a table changing only its name and the where clause.
Basically as an example:

[image]

I would like, for example, to create the table three times according to vector_a, that is, we would have a table with the name 01,02,03 and filtering from vector_b that would also change to create the table with std1 at the beginning and then std2 and std3. Being these variables inside the array in string format.

Comment: In case you are doing this to for reducing the billed amount: 
There is also a partition and clustered method for this task. With IAM you can also limit what information of a table different users can see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#for-in

You can use something like

```
DECLARE vector_a ARRAY<STRING>;
SET vector_a = ['_01', '_02', '_03'];

FOR loop_variable_name IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(vector_a))
DO
  -- use loop_variable_name here;
END FOR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight addition to the answer posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73752498/6908861

It is probably not feasible to use the variable loop_variable_name as is. It is required to cast it to STRING to make it usable.

```
DECLARE vector_a ARRAY<STRING>;
SET vector_a = ['_01', '_02', '_03'];

FOR loop_variable_name IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(vector_a))
DO
SELECT * from table1 where col1 = cast(loop_variable_name[0] as STRING)
END FOR;
```