# Error of exporting a table by its partition from bigQuery to google cloud platform storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to export a table (~ 100GB) from GCP BigQuery to GCP storage bucket.
I have add a column to the table with export_id based on the example at
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#limit_the_exported_file_size
The total partition is 128.

Now, I need to export each partition as a single parquet file (which is < 1GB) to a GCS bucket.

```
 FOR loop_variable_name IN (SELECT export_id FROM `project.dataset.my_table`)
DO

 EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
 uri='gs://my_gcp_bucket/my_folder/*',
 format='PARQUET',
  overwrite=true) 
 AS
 (
  SELECT * EXCEPT(export_id)
  FROM `project.dataset.my_table`
  WHERE export_id = loop_variable_name
 )

 END FOR; -- error: syntax error: expected ";" but got "END"
```

Could anybody let me know what I missed out ? thanks

I have tried this [Loop in BigQuery (SQL - GOOGLE CLOUD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73750237/loop-in-bigquery-sql-google-cloud)
but I got the above error.

Comment: add a ; after your latest parenthesis )

Comment: Hi @mtnt, did the above comment help you in resolving the issue ?